# PUT file (content) with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, put

I'm trying to upload a file using cURL and the PUT method, I have already a function that works using fsockopen but i would like to migrate it to cURL.

The function that uses fsockopen receives the content of a file, the filename and the credentials for auth and make the request:

```
function put_file($content, $filename, $username, $pass)
{
    $header = "PUT /upload?username=".urlencode(user_name)."&passwd=".urlencode($pass)."&filename=".urlencode($file_name)." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($content) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = @fsockopen("ssl://URL", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if(!$fp)
    {
        return "ERROR";
    }
    else
    {
        fputs ($fp, $header.$content);
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $res .= fread ($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to migrate that function to cURL, but I don't know how to do it without the need of have a "real" file on my filesystem. The only cURL options I know for this are CURLOPT_INFILE and CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, but I don't have the file (and don't want to write it to disk and after open it).

What I need is to send the "content" of the file, just like the fsockopen version does. How can this be achieved with cURL?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: may we know the purpose of migrating to cURL ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor All my app is using cURL and I would like to keep thinks uniform. Is the any inconvenient or you think is better to not use cURL in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [php://temp](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) wrapper, which is a temporary file stream in PHP.

First you write the data to the stream (don't forget to use [rewind()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) so cURL will read all data):

```
$fp = fopen("php://temp", "r+");
fputs($fp, $content);
rewind($fp);
```

Then when setting up the cURL just use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($content)); #adding missing bracket
```

And at the end close temp file handler (optional):

```
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I'm looking for a way of do it without create a temp file, just with the content I've got. Is that possible?

Comment: The php://temp wrapper will actually store its data in memory, unless the data hits the predetermined limit. As far as I know there is no way to use variable content in PUT requests with cURL. May I know the reason why you don't want to use temp file? I assume you don't send huge files, as you pass the data in a variable in the function.